# React Native error Element type is invalid: expected a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am using **react-native-sass-transformer** package with **React Native**, and I cannot get past the following error:

```
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Check the render method of `App`.

This error is located at:
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by ScrollView)
in RCTScrollView (created by ScrollView)
in ScrollView (created by ScrollView)
in ScrollView (created by App)
in App (created by ExpoRoot)
in ExpoRoot
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by AppContainer)
in AppContainer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:149:8 in registerError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:60:8 in errorImpl
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\LogBox\LogBox.js:34:4 in console.error
at node_modules\expo\build\environment\react-native-logs.fx.js:27:4 in error
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ExceptionsManager.js:172:19 in handleException
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\ReactFiberErrorDialog.js:43:2 in showErrorDialog
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15792:34 in logCapturedError
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:15884:20 in update.callback
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7199:2 in callCallback
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:7220:20 in commitUpdateQueue
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:16632:25 in commitLifeCycles
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:19216:22 in commitLayoutEffects
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:93:4 in invokeGuardedCallbackProd
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:318:2 in invokeGuardedCallback
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18952:29 in commitRootImpl
at node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:468:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18791:17 in commitRoot
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:18192:12 in performSyncWorkOnRoot
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5911:33 in runWithPriority$argument_1
at node_modules\scheduler\cjs\scheduler.development.js:468:23 in unstable_runWithPriority
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5906:23 in flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:5893:28 in flushSyncCallbackQueue
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:17745:30 in scheduleUpdateOnFiber
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:21484:23 in updateContainer
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Renderer\implementations\ReactNativeRenderer-dev.js:22144:17 in render
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\renderApplication.js:58:4 in renderApplication        
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\AppRegistry.js:117:25 in runnables.appKey.run
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\ReactNative\AppRegistry.js:202:4 in runApplication
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:414:4 in __callFunction
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:113:6 in __guard$argument_0
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:365:10 in __guard
at node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:112:4 in callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

I have added the code inside `metro.config.js` and `app.json` as specified [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/sass-react-native-guide/).

My code inside `App.js`:

```
import { ScrollView, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import LoginPage from './src/Components/Pages/LoginPage/LoginPage';

export default function App() {
    return (
        <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
            <LoginPage />
        </ScrollView>
    );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1
    }
});
```

`LoginPage.jsx`:

```
import { View } from 'react-native';
const LoginPage = () => {
    return (
        <View></View>
    );
};

export default LoginPage;
```

Even if I revert the changes made for **react-native-sass-transformer**, the error persists. I do not have any idea of what to try.

Comment: You forgot to add `import React from 'react'` in both the components. Try if this helps.

Comment: @Rohit it did, actually, thanks!

Comment: Also, it seems like I had to have ```.js``` components, **not** ```.jsx``` ones

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues but was to fix it by doing this:
Try to add `import React from 'react'`